# apalike+bibtex: letter to duplicate author-year is added not only to the key, but also to the publication year

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I've noticed a weird behavior in the generated list of references.

Bibliography included like:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{path/to/bib}
```

No weird packages included (but maybe my template does?). I'm definitely not using natbib (`grep -r natbib` in project folder doesn't return anything). I build the bibliography with bibtex.

.bib:

```
@inproceedings{Akrour,
author = {Akrour, Riad and Tateo, Davide and Peters, Jan},
booktitle = {1st Workshop on Deep Continuous-Discrete Machine Learning},
organization = {TU Darmstadt},
title = {{Towards Reinforcement Learning of Human Readable Policies}},
year = {2019}
}

@inproceedings{Akrour2019,
address = {Long Beach, California, USA},
author = {Akrour, Riad and Pajarinen, Joni and Neumann, Gerhard and Peters, Jan},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 36th International Conference on Machine Learning},
pages = {181--190},
publisher = {PMLR},
title = {{Projections for approximate policy iteration algorithms}},
volume = {97},
year = {2019}
}
```

Generated .bbl:

```
\bibitem[Akrour et~al., 2019a]{Akrour2019}
Akrour, R., Pajarinen, J., Neumann, G., and Peters, J. (2019a).
\newblock {Projections for approximate policy iteration algorithms}.
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of the 36th International Conference on Machine Learning}, volume~97, pages
  181--190, Long Beach, California, USA. PMLR.

\bibitem[Akrour et~al., 2019b]{Akrour}
Akrour, R., Tateo, D., and Peters, J. (2019b).
\newblock {Towards Reinforcement Learning of Human Readable Policies}.
\newblock In {\em 1st Workshop on Deep Continuous-Discrete Machine Learning}, TU Darmstadt.
```

Notice the publication year in the parentheses in `[Akrour et al., 2019a] Akrour, R., Pajarinen, J., Neumann, G., and Peters, J. (2019a).` I think it should only be `(2019)`, shouldn't it? How do I achieve that? Or can it be some weirdness in the template I use?

Comment: The default citation commands aren't designed for author year type styles like `apalike`.  If you load `natbib` you will get the correct output (no label in `[...]`) but the year will still have *a* and *b*, because if you are abbreviating multiple authors to just the first author, the citation call out will require the *a* and *b* and therefore the year in the bibliography will too.

Comment: What correct output? I think the letter in `[]` is okay. The letter in `()` is not okay.

Comment: An author year style looks like this: *Author, An (Year)*. It doesn't look like this *[Author et al. Year] Author, An (Year) ...*  What you have right now is weird mixture of author year and alpha styles. Run your code with `natbib` loaded to see the correct output for `apalike`.

Comment: Apparently, I don't know how to run my code with natbib. I added `\usepackage{natbib}`, but I only got tons of errors like `Argument of \org@@citex has an extra }. ...sing the action. \relax }}{23}{figure.3.2}`. I tried to fix it with `\renewcommand*\cite[1]{\citet{#1}}`, but that did not help.

Comment: Well since you didn't provide any code, it's hard to tell what's going on. Did you delete your `.aux` files and compile again?  And don't renew the `\cite` command.

Comment: Well, I'm using template https://github.com/tohecz/ctuthesis/ with `\documentclass[twoside]{ctuthesis}`. What more code would you like to see? I tried with deleting all aux files, no change. Without renewing `\cite`, the errors are the same.

Comment: We can't debug your thesis for you. The class you're loading has no problem with `natbib`, though.

Comment: Found it, package `cite` was interfering with natbib. When I commented it out, natbib succeeded. The generated citation is `Akrour (2019a)` (which I consider correct), and the item in bibliography list is `Akrour, R., Pajarinen, J., Neumann, G., and Peters, J. (2019a).` (which I consider weird). It seems this "solution" works by removing the citation key `[Akrour et al., 2019a]` from literature list. Then, really, the year in `()` is the only logical place where the `a` can go, but it still seems weird to me. So is it an inherent property of bibtex that it needs to change the year everywhere?

Comment: No, this is not an inherent property of `bibtex`, or TeX at all,  it's how any author year system is designed to work: by design, the citation callouts (i) must be unique and (ii) must match the bibliography items. So if you are abbreviating author names in the callouts to first author + et al. then the 'a' and 'b' labels must appear to disambiguate (satisfying (i)) and  must also appear in the bibliography (satisfying (ii)). If you spelled out the authors in full in all citations, then you wouldn't require the 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Okay, maybe there was a little confusion because I did not output the whole line of bibliography. The original output without natbib generated this: `[Akrour et al., 2019a] Akrour, R., Pajarinen, J., Neumann, G., and Peters, J. (2019a). ...`. Here you see that in the `[]` the year-letter is used, as well as in `()`. My question is if it can show only in `[]` and not in `()`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Now we’re going around in circles. If you want this style don’t use `apalike`.

Comment: Okay, so back to the original question. How do I achieve the style I described? I.e. intext citation `[Akrour et al., 2019a]` with bibliography entry `[Akrour et al., 2019a] Akrour, R., Pajarinen, J., Neumann, G., and Peters, J. (2019). ...`?

Comment: I doubt such a style exists, since it is mixing two fundamentally different ways of doing citations and bibliography. And it is certainly not the APA style. Why don't you use the style that is commonly used by journals in your field?

Comment: Well, this is a thesis. And each journal uses a different style, there's nothing like a single "canonical" journal in robotics. Keeping things simple, I wanted to stay with bibtex and have author-year citations which I consider more appropriate in a text which is not length-limited. Anyways, thanks for your help. Now I see that What I wanted was probably impossible, and I'll either have to find a different style or give up and leave the few weird references as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've learned in the comments that what I'm trying to achieve might not be the best idea, I found a way to do it.

I needed to edit the file `apalike.bst` distributed with my tex like this:

```
*** /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/apalike.bst   2020-04-30 05:30:21.838947719 +0200
--- ctu-apalike.bst 2020-04-30 05:31:59.251578754 +0200
***************
*** 121,127 ****
  { year empty$
      { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      { write$
!       " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
        mid.sentence 'output.state :=
      }
    if$
--- 121,127 ----
  { year empty$
      { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      { write$
!       " (" year * ")" *
        mid.sentence 'output.state :=
      }
    if$
```